# Is it possible to build a complete web site with Drupal 7 without using contributed modules or Hooks?

Tags: 7, hooks

Is it a good programming practice to add your own hooks in a template.tpl.php or is it best practice to make all the changes possible into a custom module?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what you need to know - there's no possible way to answer this in its current form, as obviously whether or not you need to use contributed modules, or write your own, is 100% reliant on what the website needs to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the site's requirements. If you want to create a site only for content listing, you can simply change in template files to make it as per design. But you must keep your theme in `sites/all/themes` directory.

But generally the requirements are not so simple. The modules are contributed to make the better user experience. If you are asking this question for the better performance of site, then you should maintain your site with drupal standard.

The things to keep in mind :

1. Use contributed module rather than writing custom module.
2. In some case if you have to write custom module, then use drupal functions and API rather than core PHP functions.
3. Always keep your site (drupal/modules) updated with security releases.

Comment: Good basic advice for a very basic (and unclear) question. +1

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, I was not able to edit the question til now. Sumit Madan gave an splendid reply. From his words, now I understand that basically I should follow this work flow: 1. Use contributed modules. 2. Write custom module and use hooks there. 3. Use hooks in template.tpl.php. 4. NEVER EVER -- hack the core.

Comment: @Cesar One thin more I forgot to tell.. Avoid PHP in Database.. :D